# DatabaseContext always got reinitialized and didn't keep states when using generic repository pattern

Tags: generics, repository, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

Trying to figure out how to share the same instance of my context upon my application but the DBContext keeps reinitialized in each and every request losing its states.
i have one dbfactory which is responsible for initalizing my context.

```
public class DbFactory: Disposable, IDbFactory
{
    GamaTaskDbContext dbContext;

    public GamaTaskDbContext Init()
    {
        return dbContext ?? (dbContext = new GamaTaskDbContext());
    }

    protected override void DisposeCore()
    {
        if (dbContext != null)
            dbContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I have also one generic repository class,where the problem is that each request triggers the repository constructor and found the dbContext is null & reinitialized it, so with each request i have new instance of context class which lead that i failed to remove entities of course as the context which fetches data is different than what is trying to remove it.

```
 public abstract class Repository<Tentity> where Tentity : class
{
    private  GamaTaskDbContext dataContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<Tentity> dbSet;


    protected IDbFactory DbFactory
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    protected GamaTaskDbContext DbContext
    {
        get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DbFactory.Init());}
    }
    public Repository(IDbFactory dbFactory)
    {
        DbFactory = dbFactory;
        dbSet = DbContext.Set<Tentity>();

    }
```

IOC configuartion

```
      private static void SetAutofacContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Repositories
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CustomerRepository).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
        // Services
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(CustomerService).Assembly)
           .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

        builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            foreach (var profile in c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>())
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(profile);
            }
        })).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>()
                 .CreateMapper(c.Resolve))
                 .As<IMapper>()
                 .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency Injection is just the pattern where the caller is in control of all dependencies. That doesn't just mean that the caller is the one that decides which class to use for each interface, but also how long the injected object lives.

An inversion of control container isn't just used to resolve all dependencies, but also to make sure that a new object is created when required and that all disposable objects are disposed when the time is right.

Objects that must have a specific lifetime are called scoped objects. For web applications a lifetime scope is typically the duration of a HTTP request.

In your example you are trying to both keep control and let the inversion of control container do the work. Let the container manage the lifetime of your dbcontext. By doing so, it will create it when the first class requests it as a dependency, and then pass the same dbContext instance to all other classes that needs it.

Let go of the control, and everything will work fine.

Thus I would just have this code:

```
public abstract class Repository<Tentity> where Tentity : class
{
    private  GamaTaskDbContext _dataContext;
    private readonly IDbSet<Tentity> dbSet;


    public Repository(GamaTaskDbContext dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
        dbSet = _dataContext .Set<Tentity>();

    }
protected GamaTaskDbContext DbContext
{
    get { return _dataContext; }
}
```

And register it like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<GamaTaskDbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

No need to do anything else.

*There are very few cases when you really want the DbContext to live for the duration of multiple http requests. Typically it just hurt more than you gain.*

Comment: Many thanks jquaffin for your illustration, i totally agree with what you have said.i was just overwhelmed with who should done the work me & how should it be done so i was thinking should i let the container do it or i need to control the flow of instantiating & disposing with other aspects).anyway container makes my life easier.